# How can streaming with microphone and background audio(other App) on WebRTC/IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, avaudiosession

I making some chat app with the WebRTC in iOS.

I set `AVAudioSession` like this:

```swift
let configuration = RTCAudioSessionConfiguration.init()
configuration.category = AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord.rawValue;
configuration.categoryOptions = [.mixWithOthers]
configuration.mode = AVAudioSession.Mode.voiceChat.rawValue;
```

This setting is works well. Playing well the background audio when I use the microphone. But stream sound is only from the microphone. I want to stream the microphone sound with background sound.

Anybody knows this?

Thank you.